# Set min date in bootstrap datetimepicker 2

Tags: datetimepicker

How to set minimum date in **bootstrap datetimepicker 2.0**. In 4.0 we can use `minDate` is there any way to set this in version 2.0

Comment: Which component are you using? Can you link it? What have you tried? Please read the here to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes use `startDate`

Refer more:
http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#startdate

Use like this

```
<div class="input-append date form_datetime" data-date="2013-02-21T15:25:00Z">
    <input size="16" type="text" value="" readonly>
    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".form_datetime").datetimepicker({
        format: "dd MM yyyy - hh:ii",
        startDate: "2013-02-14 10:00",
    });
</script>
```

Comment: this doesnt solve ur problem?? Why u unmarked it as answer

Comment: It solved my problem. For bootstrap datetimepicker 4.0 we can use minDate option and for bootstrap datetimepicker 2.0 we can use this method startDate.

Comment: Yes u used startDate as I suggested, value of startDate doesnt matter.. I just give a example in my solution. If u find it useful, mark it as answer, so others with similar problem may find it useful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Bootstrap datetimepicker v 4.x**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var date = new Date();
    var today = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate()+1);
    $('#datePicker1').datetimepicker({
        minDate: today
    })
});
```

**Bootstrap datetimepicker v 2.0**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var date = new Date();
    var today = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate()+1);
    $('#datePicker1').datetimepicker({
        startDate: today
    })
});
```